# How to get ASP.NET Session object from a WebSocket request?

Tags: asp.net, websocket, session-state

I implemented a custom web handler (ashx) page in my existing ASP.NET project which uses the Session object to know which user is requests pages.  The web handler works except for one major draw back.  The Session object is not available to my Websocket handler task.

I tried calling `HttpContext.Current.Session` but it is null.

Any suggestions?

**Update**

Thanks to Karl Anderson's response, I was able to make some head way, however the issue still stands.  My code in the handler is as follows:

```
public class WSHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            string s = context.Session["UserName"]; // This works now!
            context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(ProcessWebSocket);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    private async Task ProcessWebSocket(AspNetWebSocketContext context)
    {
        string s = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"]; // This still doesn't.  The Session property is null
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best that I was able to come up with was to create a method which invokes a web form to get/set session data.  I understand that this isn't very efficient however I don't see any other way to do this.

**Edit:**
In order for this to work you need to enable Cookieless sessions in the Web.Config file.  This could be a big security risk for most sites so remember to implement logic to prevent session hijacking!  I am currently using IP verification along with browser fingerprint checking.

I created a class that I use in my WebSocket handler (WSHandler.ashx):

```
public class SessionData
{
    AspNetWebSocketContext _WebSocketContext = null;

    public SessionData(AspNetWebSocketContext WebSocketContext)
    {
        _WebSocketContext = WebSocketContext;
    }

    public string GetSessionValue(string name)
    {
        string value = "";

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            string Url = _WebSocketContext.Origin + _WebSocketContext.RawUrl.Replace("WSHandler.ashx", "UpdateSession.aspx");
            Url += "?a=1";
            Url += "&n=" + name;
            value = wc.DownloadString(Url);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public void PutSessionValue(string name, string value)
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            string Url = _WebSocketContext.Origin + _WebSocketContext.RawUrl.Replace("WSHandler.ashx", "UpdateSession.aspx");
            Url += "?a=2";
            Url += "&n=" + name;
            Url += "&v=" + value;
            wc.DownloadString(Url);
        }
    }

}
```

Below is the form for the web form UpdateSession.aspx:

```
public partial class UpdateSession : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string action = Page.Request.QueryString["a"];
        string name = Page.Request.QueryString["n"];
        string value = Page.Request.QueryString["v"];

        Page.Response.Clear();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) == true)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (action)
        {
            case "1":
                if (Session[name] != null)
                {
                    Page.Response.Write(Session[name].ToString());
                }
                break;

            case "2":
                Session[name] = value;
                break;
        }

        Page.Response.End();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to read from the `Session` object, then you need to implement `IReadOnlySessionState` in your HTTP Handler code, like this:

```
public class YourHandler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext theContext)
    {
        theContext.Response.Write(theContext.Session["YOUR_VALUE_HERE"]);
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }
}
```

If you want to be able to read from and write to the `Session` object, then you need to implement the `IRequiresSessionState` in your HTTP Handler code.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the write track.  I am now able to access the Session object from the `ProcessRequest` method.  However my `AcceptWebSocketRequest` task doesn't have the Session available, which is were I need it.  I will add my code to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Session is intentionally not made available to the WebSocket handling loop since Session has a default two-minute timeout and WebSocket connections could theoretically last forever.

If you need to read data from Session, read the individual objects ahead of time (in the main ProcessRequest method) and squirrel it away somewhere, like in a private field.  If you need to write data back to Session, you'll need to use a different mechanism (such as an actual database table) rather than using Session itself.

Comment: I think you meant to say 20 minute timeout and not two-minute ;)
You do make a good point, however.  But I was planning on making the Session object dirty if there is activity from the websocket so that the user's session doesn't expire.

Comment: @vbguyny Nope, I meant two-minute. Session objects are not thread-safe, so the ASP.NET runtime serializes access to these objects. Requests which depend on these Session objects are delayed until the objects are unlocked. This locking mechanism has a two-minute timeout, and a long-lived WebSocket request would blow well past that timeout. The end result is a corrupt Session object since multiple threads would be trying to access it simultaneously. Hence we don't make it available in the WebSocket pipeline.

Comment: I understand.  I got timeout confused with expire.  That is an interesting issue.  I will need to verify that.